# A string resource from an Android lib overrides a resource from the app with the same name

Tags: android, lint

I created a simple Android project out of my curiosity. It contains two modules: `app` and `lib`. Each module has its own package name. I created one string resource in the lib module and one string resource in the app module. Like this:

`<string name="my_str">my_str_from_lib</string>`

`<string name="my_str">my_str_from_app</string>`

Then I set the texts to two `TextView`s in the app module:

```
fromLib.text = resources.getString(ru.maksim.sample.lib1.R.string.my_str) // here I expected to see the string from the lib.
fromApp.text = resources.getString(R.string.my_str)
```

In both cases it was `my_str_from_`**app**
I ran Lint and thought it would detect the fact of resource overriding. But it didn't. 
Is there a chance to detect this situation? Not necessarily with Lint. Other tools suit me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is a script that parses a resulting XML to which all the string from the main app module and all its libraries are merged and finds all the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do a global search in your root folder. Find all instances of my_str and make sure its only the string.xml in your app that uses it as name.

Comment: it would work for a _very small_ project. In the real world it's no option

Comment: It should work big or small project. You are just searching basically.

Comment: What if I have 5000 strings in my project? And 20 libraries.